# Проблема с высотой блока flex

Tags: flexbox, height

Есть секция с портфолио у которой задан Display:flex секции внутри сделаны через ссылки при этом внутри них лежит текст img но он не занимает 100% высоты а немного больше не могу понять почему.
[image: flex block внутри]

[image: картинка внутри ссылки]

Comment: вы не знали картинки занимают чуть больше потому они ниже себя оставляют пространство вообще точек бы не помешало а так картинкам нужно дисплей блок сделать он обычно помогает от этого

Comment: Действительно помогло спасибо

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но либо в normalize.css, либо в reset.css это фиксится. Если не прав - стукните по голове.

Comment: @AlbertAkmukhametow, еще молитвой, бывает, фиксится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирай:

```
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```